# Representing routing table using threads in C - homework Task

Tags: c, multithreading, networking, routes, task

so, I have been given this task at my school and it driving me crazy so far. I got no clue how to begin, I will sure glad to get some help about it.
The task is translated, So Im terribly sorry about the results of it's translation, I warn you guys, it's translated pretty bad.

this is another problem I have with this task, the translation is awful and I don't have the original source of it.

### The Task:

Routing table in threads

**Introduction**

Network computers (locally or broad) there are several computers (nodes) various locations.

To send information from one junction to a second, intersection is not always found a direct link between the nodes lines. In this case we will have to send via Route
A few nodes. 
There may be no connection at all between the two nodes that have no way to send them.
Network nodes can be represented by the adjacency matrix with 1 indicates that a direct link between the nodes and 0 shows no such relationship.

**1**  **2**   **3**   **4**   **5**

**1**  1   1   0   0   1

**2**  1   1   1   0   1

**3**  0   1   1   1   0

**4**  0   0   1   1   0

**5**  1   1   0   0   1

Real network nodes can also disappear temporary or final , so need to constantly update the connectivity table.

In the main exercise we assume nodes do not disappear or go out of commission even once.

While in section 4 (bonus) nodes can change
 
Description of task
 
Each node in your system will be represented by thread . The purpose of the program is :
Receive the data from the initial network of nodes and links , and update the global routing table .
Each thread needs to work on the line (and column) his table , and if it does not have direct contact with node , 
then searches if there is an indirect connection, If found to be an indirect connection via other nodes , then the thread will mark this connection in the table.

Table will be a number that symbolises the weight of the relationship - if it is not just between Junction

One then has 0 arcs and weight 0 , if the three arches weight 3, and so on. 
For example: the relationship between 1 and 4
Table above is a weight 3 . . The first thread - main need to make a few things :

- absorb the user the number of nodes to 02
- user pick the topology of the network in the following way :
   id1 id2 id5; id2 id3 id5; id3 id4;
   Example ; 1 2 5 , 2 3 5 ; 3 4 marks end of list node 's direct neighbours
  Means : Node 1 is related to 0 and 5 , node 0 is also related to 3 and 5 , node 3 is related to 4.
- create the initial connectivity table and displayed on the screen
- create the proper number of threads according to the number of nodes
- wait for all the threads
- After all the threads have finished and there will be more updates, the program displays the main table
- End with an appropriate message Final Table Network
- end the program after eliminating all the objects we have built , for example , thread attributes
  mutexes , mutex attributes , condition variables , condition variable
   attributes

### What does each node denotes thread :

- looking for a possible link route (recursively) all the nodes that it is not related to
  Directly. If found new contact , update the table by finding the smallest weight
- concurrency to simulate a real system , it is recommended that each thread will sleep a random time before search
- The thread should remember finding the shortest route and print it as the final search
  Example :
   thread N connected to M by: N-> node1-> node2-> .... -> M
- If the thread and update the table - before he finishes it also print his line
  Table updated with the appropriate message :
   thread updated line N N - the connections now are: 1 0 2 1 1 4
   closing thread N - no updates to network table or
  No need to print messages about updating a single value - just post when finishing line.

Comment: TL;DR: If you have a problem, split it into smaller problems first. Don't just dump entire assigment here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty big assignment. No one here will help you code the entire thing, but I will give you some hints.

1. Use a `pthread_t` for each node
2. Use pipes `man 2 pipe` to model the connections.
   Put the pipes into a matrix

   ```
   int connections[NUMTHREADS][NUMTHREADS][2];
   ```

   Where `connections[i][j][0]` is the read end for node `i` to receive from `j` (by column) and `connections[i][j][1]` is the write end for node `j` to send to `i` (by row). Note that `-1` is an invalid file descriptor.
3. Have each thread `select` (`man 2 select`) on it's valid read ends waiting for receiving data and then broadcast to all nodes it is connected to with a TTL (so you don't get infinite loops).
4. Have all nodes regularly broadcast some sort of shortest path synchronisation message. Then each receiver can adjust his shortest path to each node every now and then. Have your `select` time out for this.

Comment: Thank you! at least now I have something to start with, I sure hope to succeed this one. it sure seems like a big task.

Comment: Communication between nodes is not part of the task, it's about making a _global routing table_, so there's no need for the pipes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of the main exercise without the bonus, so nodes don't change. For the sake of simplicity, the maximum node number is nine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// A route is stored in the routing table as an integer number with the nodes
// from start to end represented by the decimal digits from lowest to highest.

int routelg(int rt)
{   // compute the length of a route
    int lg = 0;
    while (rt) ++lg, rt /= 10;
    return lg;
}

void display(int n, sig_atomic_t table[n][n])
{
    int k, l;
    printf(" "); for (k = 0; k++ < n; ) printf(" %d", k); puts("");
    printf(" "); for (k = 0; k++ < n; ) printf("--");     puts("");
    for (                    l = 0; l < n; ++l, puts(""))
    for (printf("%d|", 1+l), k = 0; k < n; ++k)
        printf("%d ", routelg(table[l][k]));
}

int n;
sig_atomic_t (*global_routing_table)[];

#define IN(lo, hi, num) lo <= num && num <= hi

int router(sig_atomic_t table[n][n], int origin, int destin, int visited[n])
{   // looking for a possible link route (recursively)
    int hops = table[origin][destin], hop, hopmin = 999999999, l;
    if (hops) return hops;  // already have the path
    visited[origin] = 1;
    for (l = 0; l < n; ++l)
        if (IN(11, 99, table[origin][l]) && !visited[l])
        {   // directly connected and not already tried
            hop = router(table, l, destin, visited);
            if (hop && hop < hopmin) hopmin = hops = hop*10+1+origin;
        }
    visited[origin] = 0;
    return hops;
}

void *route(void *arg)
{
    int i = (int)arg, k, visited[n], rt;
    sig_atomic_t (*table)[n] = global_routing_table;
    for (k = 0; k < n; ++k)
        if (!table[i][k])   // no route (yet) from here (i) to node k
        {
            memset(visited, 0, sizeof visited);
            rt = table[i][k] = router(table, i, k, visited);
            flockfile(stdout);
            printf("%d %sconnected to %d", 1+i, rt ? "" : "un", 1+k);
            char *del;
            for (del = " by:"; rt; rt /= 10, del = "->")
                printf("%s %d", del, rt%10);
            puts("");
            funlockfile(stdout);
        }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    printf("number of nodes (max 9)? "), scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("topology of the network? ");
    sig_atomic_t table[n][n];
    int i;
    memset(table, 0, sizeof table);
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) table[i][i] = 1+i;
    do
    {   int neighbours[n];
        for (i = 0; scanf("%d ", &neighbours[i]) > 0; ++i) ;
        int o = neighbours[0];
        while (--i > 0) table[o-1][neighbours[i]-1] = o+10*neighbours[i],
                        table[neighbours[i]-1][o-1] = neighbours[i]+10*o;
    } while (getchar() == ';');
    puts("initial connectivity table:"), display(n, table);
    pthread_t threads[n];
    global_routing_table = table;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) pthread_create(threads+i, NULL, route, (void *)i);
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    puts("final table (0 - no route, 1..n - weight+1):"), display(n, table);
}
```